# Wordpress error connecting to database but it's correct

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, database, wordpress

I've been struggling to find the problem but I just seem to be going around in circles and most of the tutorials just tell me to check the mysql credentials but I'm sure that they're right.

I have an Ubuntu 19.10 server on my LAN that I'm using to test and learn. I'm trying to install Wordpress using the LAMP stack installed from tasksel. I'm using another computer and ssh to edit configs and then going to the server ip in the browser from that computer.

Here I create three new databases, three new users with the same password.
I'm trying to see if specifying @localhost or @*severip* will help.
[mysql databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcRKz.png)
I realized that I forgot to grant privileges to two.
[granting privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQab.png)

Then after following the downloading, unzip instructions for three different copies in /var/www/html/. I went to the *serverip*/wordpress/public_html and tried to install through the wizard.
You can see that the database name, user, and password are correct for all three sites. 
[wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WISjH.png) [wordpressdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR3ik.png) [wordpressBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVvFP.png)
All give me the same error
[error connecting to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seBDv.png)

Following, I'm only showing stuff one site but I tried the same with all three (changing to fit each directory/database).

Editing the wp-config.php file gives me a similar error but it's just "Error establishing database" without the explanation.
[my wp-config.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9EMg.png)

I followed a tutorial that had me change AllowOverride to All in my apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is my wordpress.conf in sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.0.0.58/wordpress             

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/public_html/

    LogLevel debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wordpressError.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wordpressAccess.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteOptions inherit

 </VirtualHost>
```

I set the logging to debug and to a separate log file but nothing seems to be writing there.

I also created a blank .htaccess per a tutorial.

I am not sure where else to look, every tutorial or thread I find has the same steps I've been following but when it gets to the point where you enter the database information it gives me that error, even if my password is correct.

I am thinking it might have something to do with the mysql database?
Can someone help point me in the right direction for what to check?

Answer (score 0):

What dose the log file says?

Actually I faced the same issue. Everything works fine when I deleted "AllowOverride All" from the wordpress.conf. Try to do the same and then restart your server.